# Android: How do you define buttons and other widgets outside of a layout?

Tags: android, layout, button, widget, android-framelayout

So generally you define an XML layout with a single root node and all the buttons and such contained inside.  But if you want to just define buttons somewhere so you can reference their IDs later on to move them around, where/how do you do that?

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to use the "android:foreground" field in the FrameLayout.  So I want to point this to the ID of a button (or other widget) that I've defined.  But where do I define this button (or other widget)?  If I just defined it normally wouldn't it end up appearing somewhere where I don't want it to?

Answer (score 0):

android:foreground adds a drawable over the layout as an overlay. you put the drawable in /res/drawable

As for the buttons, you can always code them in the java

Answer (score 0):

Just define your button in `my_button.xml` file in `res/layout` folder with any attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ... 
    style="@style/MyStyle" />
```

And then inflate it when needed:

```
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_button, null);
```